# Simple vector/matrix norm questions

Tags: linear-algebra

(1) If I have a column vector $x$ and it's transpose $x^T$ (a row vector), can I say $$\|x^T\|_2\|x\|_2 = \|x\|^2_2$$
(2) Additionally, am I correct in believing that $\|x^T\|_2\|B\|_2 \geq \|x^TB\|_2$ for a compatible dimension matrix $B$?